# How to unit test a Web API controller using XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, webapi

I am trying to unit test a method within my controller in my Web API using XUnit. The role of the method is to get a single title, by ISBN, from the database. The issue I came across during unit testing is that I am unsure how to insert the dummy data that I must perform the test on, as well as how the Assert function works.

**TitleController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("titlecontroller")]
public class TitleController : Controller
{
    private IGtlTitleRepository _gtlTitleRepository;

    public TitleController(IGtlTitleRepository gtlTitleRepository)
    {
        _gtlTitleRepository = gtlTitleRepository;
    }

    [Route("getTitle/{ISBN}")]
    [HttpGet()]
    public GtlTitle GetTitle(string ISBN)    
    {
        return _gtlTitleRepository.GetTitle(ISBN);
    }
}
```

**IGtlTitleRepository.cs**

```
    public interface IGtlTitleRepository
{
    GtlTitle GetTitle(string ISBN);
}
```

**MockGtlTitleRepository.cs**

```
    public class MockGtlTitleRepository : IGtlTitleRepository
{
    private readonly string _connection;
    public MockGtlTitleRepository(IOptions<ConnectionStringList> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connection = connectionStrings.Value.GTLDatabase;
    }


    private List<GtlTitle> _titleList;

    public GtlTitle GetTitle(string ISBN)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.QuerySingle<GtlTitle>("GetTitleByISBN", new { ISBN }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

}
```

Right, as for my test code, I was able to write the following code, but as I said above, I can't figure out a proper way to test the method.

```
 public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {

        var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGtlTitleRepository>();
        var title = new GtlTitle();
        repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetTitle("978-0-10074-5")).Returns(title);
        var controller = new TitleController(repositoryMock.Object);

        var result = controller.GetTitle("978-0-10074-5");
       // assert??
        repositoryMock.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

What should be done within this unit test in order to properly test the method?

**EDIT:**

**GtlTitle.cs**

```
public class GtlTitle
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string VolumeName { get; set; }
    public string TitleDescription { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PublisherName { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: can you show us `GtlTitle` class?

Comment: I edited the original post with it!

Comment: Just check that result from controller equals to title `Assert.Equal(title, result);`?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://exceptionnotfound.net/unit-testing-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers-with-moq-and-xunit/ ... it should be useful for you

Comment: @Prasad Could the expected output result be the object queried? For example, I want to verify that my method when called with parameter "978-0-10074-5" can return the following:`{"isbn":"978-0-10074-5","volumeName":"Volume Name - 97581","titleDescription":"Description - 97581","firstName":"First Name - 560","lastName":"Last Name - 560","publisherName":"Publisher - 714"}`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you! That line of code worked but...Is that it? I assume that line `repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.GetTitle("978-0-10074-5")).Returns(title);` basically mocked a database object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before going to testing, there are a few things I recommend updating in your code:

- Make your repository methods and controller actions async (thus web server can process requests while waiting for database roundtrips for previous calls)
- Use `ActionResult` as an action return type. This way you can send different http status codes to the client.
- Return 404 NotFound status code when title not found instead of returning successful result with `null` as payload.
- Consider using a RESTful approach for API endpoints. E.g. base uri for titles resource should be something like `api/titles`
- Don't specify `getTitle` for getting title endpoint, because you know HTTP verb which endpoint is mapped to (GET) and base resource url (api/titles).

With these notes applied:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/titles")]
public class TitleController : Controller
{
    private IGtlTitleRepository _gtlTitleRepository;

    public TitleController(IGtlTitleRepository gtlTitleRepository)
    {
        _gtlTitleRepository = gtlTitleRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet("{ISBN}")] // GET api/titles/{ISBN}
    public async Task<ActionResult<GtlTitle>> GetTitle(string ISBN)    
    {
        var title = await _gtlTitleRepository.GetTitle(ISBN);
        if (title == null)
            return NotFound();

        return title;
    }
}
```

Testing successful title retrieving:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Return_Title_When_Title_Found()
{
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGtlTitleRepository>();
    var title = new GtlTitle();
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Get("978-0-10074-5")).Returns(Task.FromResult(title));

    var controller = new TitleController(repositoryMock.Object);

    var result = await controller.GetTitle("978-0-10074-5");
    Assert.Equal(title, result.Value);
}
```

When title not found:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Should_Return_404_When_Title_Not_Found()
{
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGtlTitleRepository>();
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Get("978-0-10074-5")).Returns(Task.FromResult<GtlTitle>(null));

    var controller = new TitleController(repositoryMock.Object);

    var result = await controller.GetTitle("978-0-10074-5");
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(result.Result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response! It is incredibly useful.

Comment: I guess, that you should use something like `return Ok(title);` instead of just `return title;` in controller

Comment: On line `await _gtlTitleRepository.GetTitle(ISBN);`, it says that `GtlTitle does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter``. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete this old issue:
Regarding the last question from @Questieme:
The method has no definition of GetAwaiter, because it is just a void Method and not a task ;).

Comment: I don't belleve this is correct, GetTtitle does return something. The issue seems to lie in the return value. Not sure but i believe  Ok(title) is expected to work.

Comment: I think you mixed the repository with the controller.
If he didn't changed the repository it is still not a task:
 'public GtlTitle GetTitle(string ISBN)'
It's only a task in the controller of the answer from @SergeyBerezovskiy.
And also this error message says it pretty clear what the problem is.