# Assert.Equal can not convert error while xUnit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, webapi

I am trying to test the following method:

```
[Route("api/title")]
[HttpPost()]
public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{
    string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";
    Match m = Regex.Match(gtlTitle.ISBN, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
    else
        return BadRequest("Could not match");

}
```

For the positive test case, I wrote the following code:

```
[Fact]
public void Insert_Title_When_ISBN_Valid()
{
    DateTime d = new DateTime(1999, 6, 1);
    var repositoryMock = new Mock<IGtlTitleRepository>();
    var title = new GtlTitle() { ISBN = "978-0-105-696", VolumeName = "vname", TitleDescription = "desc", PublicationDate = d, 
                                     AuthorID = 2, PublisherID = 2, TempID = 77774};
    repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.InsertTitle(title)).Returns(title);

    var controller = new TitleController(repositoryMock.Object);

    var result = controller.InsertTitle(title);
    Assert.Equal(title, result);
}
```

On line: `Assert.Equal(title, result);` I am getting the following errors:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from "GTL.Models.Books.GtlTitle' to 'string'
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult' to string

What is going wrong with my unit test? Why does is it expecting the objects to be of type string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller action returns `IActionResult`, but you are comparing it to `Title` object. You should instead check if it's `OkObjectResult` and validate it's value:

```
var result = controller.InsertTitle(title);
var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
Assert.Equal(title, okResult.Value);
```

Comment: Does it really different from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62001121/4728685 ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski different action results and different errors, but yes both about testing aspnet core controllers